# How does MariaDB bypass InnoDB multicolumn index limit of 16?

Tags: indexing, mariadb, innodb

I'm working with a client who has multicolumn indexes set up on a local dev environment with MariaDB 10.4, and somehow he's not getting the 1070 error that would normally come up if it's over 16 columns.  Everything I've researched says this is a hard limit in InnoDB.  Is there some plugin or setting in MariaDB that allows this?

Context: Azure is sunsetting their MariaDB dbaas in 2025, so I need to figure out if there is something we can do with the current env on MySQL8 instead of switching to MariaDB.

Comment: If you must move away from MariaDB, check for usage of Engines other than InnoDB.  Also, check for usage of `@var := ...` in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

Technically the limit is defined by [sql/sql_const.h](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-5.5.20-alpha/sql/sql_const.h#L33) as 32 in MariaDB from 5.5.20, 13 years ago. It seemed to be an easy change at the time. The MySQL limit (same file) remains at 16.

If you want to change it in MariaDB you can change this constant and compile the MariaDB code. Maybe you can convince Azure or MySQL to raise this limit.

I'm sorry Azure is forcing this downgrade in capability for you. I sincerely hope MariaDB can remain a preferred choice for you.

Disclaimer: MariaDB Foundation employee

Comment: Do you have a list of things that will break when moving to 8.0?  (I added a couple of things in a Comment above.)

Comment: The [Extensions and New Features](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-10-4-and-mysql-8-/). Its actively maintained, do let us know if anything is missing (or you can edit yourself).

Comment: Dan - Thanks for the link.  I have not yet spotted anything [yet].  Z - Start new Questions if you need other workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the queries and table definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) that depend on such large composite indexes.  I would argue that the size of the index possibly counteracts the benefit of having so many columns.

A technique to improve performance is to use the clustering of the PK.  A typical table looks like:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(foo)
```

If many of the important queries have `WHERE foo = ...`, then it *may* be beneficial to change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(foo, id),
INDEX(id)   -- enough to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

I would need to see your situation to discuss how this might be enough of a performance improvement to justify having shorter indexes.